# Update Embedded Ruby Values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am looking for a way to update ruby global variables in javascript.

Say I have two values defined: `<%@value1=[]%> <%@value2=[]%>`, both equal to blank arrays. How can I updates these array using javascript?

Thank you. Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: _update ruby global variables in javascript_ - i believe there is no way to do it. `<%@value1=[]%>` compiled on the server to the js code. You cant update it on the client side.

Comment: How would I go along to update a table bassed on what is selected by the user in input. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: It is absolutely impossible to update  server-side variables with client-side code. They code rendered to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use AJAX to hit the server with your new value and change the ruby (server) value there.

Comment: And here. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp. Just google Ajax jquery examples and try some of the example code. IF you use the google chrome browser you can view the request in your developer tools. There you can see the request sent to the server and what the server responded with. Hope that Helps!